# How to create virtual properties with jackson for a map

Tags: java, dictionary, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I have a simple POJO which contains a Map<String, String> and want the entries of the Map as root level properties inside the JSON on serialization.

```
public class Element {
  public Map<String, String> props;
}
```

If this Element is serialized I get:

```
{
  "props": {
    "xxx": "yyy",
    "zzz": "aaa"
  }
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
  "prop#xxx": "yyy",
  "prop#zzz": "aaa"
}
```

I tried adding @JsonSerialize(using=PropsSerializer.class) with the following serialize method:

```
public void serialize(Map<String, String> customProperties, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
  generator.writeStartObject();
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : customProperties.entrySet()) {
    generator.writeObjectField("XXX#" + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

But this results in:

```
{
  "props": {
    "prop#xxx": "yyy",
    "prop#zzz": "aaa"
  }
}
```

If I don't use generator.writeStartObject() I get an exception that a property is written but a value is expected.

Is there a way to achive this with jackson and annotations/infos inside the POJO?